# how to use C++11 integral_constant::value_type()

Tags: c++11

I am learning to use C++ 11 type_traits, in integral_constant, there is a function value_type();

I tried this but got error:

```
typedef std::integral_constant<int, 1> one_t;
one_t one_o;
one_o.value_type();
```

> ../src/main.cc:13:9: error: cannot refer to type member 'value_type'
>   in 'one_t' (aka 'integral_constant') with '.'
>   one_o.value_type();

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well the *function* `value_type()` is not really a function with that name. Indeed, the definition of `integral_constant` looks like this:

```
template <class T, T v>
struct integral_constant {
    // ...
    typedef T value_type;
    constexpr operator value_type() const noexcept { return value; }
};
```

Notice that `value_type` is actually a `typedef` for the template parameter `T` (`int`, in OP's example). In addition there's a conversion operator that converts from `integral_constant<T, v>` to `T`. It's implicitly called like this

```
int i = one_o; // same as int i = 1;
```

To call it explicitly you need to use the `operator` keyword and the right type like this:

```
one_o.operator int();
```

which, thanks to the `typedef` member, is also equivalent to

```
one_o.operator one_t::value_type();
```

Comment: why provide `operator value_type()`, if `static constexprT value = val;` is already defined in  `template <typename T, T val>`? @cassio-neri

Comment: I think It's just for convenient, e.g., you can use `bool b=std::true_type()`, rather than `bool b=std::true_type::value`. @athos

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a temporary object of type `int`, then you should write like this.

```
typedef std::integral_constant<int, 1> one_t;
one_t one_o;
one_t::value_type();
```

If you meant `operator value_type()`, which is a conversion operator, then do it like this.

```
typedef std::integral_constant<int, 1> one_t;
one_t one_o;
int something = static_cast<value_type>(one_o);
```